# Unicode shapes in Shiny ggplot show up locally but fail in Docker and Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, docker, ggplot2, shiny, unicode

I am working on a shinyapp that involves using the `shape` argument in `geom_point` to plot unicode symbols. The plots look as intended when I run the app locally on my laptop (running Linux Mint) but I cannot get the symbols to plot correctly either on shinyapps.io or in a docker container. I found some suggestions to use `geom_text` instead of `geom_point` but I get the same issue with that.
A small example using the [baby bottle](https://codepoints.net/U+1F37C?lang=en) unicode character:
app.r

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui<-fluidPage(plotOutput("plot"),
              plotOutput("plot2"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df<-data.frame(x=0:10,
                 y=0:10)
  # plot using unicode symbols as shapes
  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    df%>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),shape="\U0001F37C",size=20)+
      scale_shape_manual(values="\U0001F37C")
  })
  # plot using built in ggplot shapes
  output$plot2<-renderPlot({
    df%>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),shape=18,size=20)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Dockerfile for container (I tried setting the language to see if that would solve it)

```
# get shiny server and R from the rocker project
FROM rocker/shiny-verse

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y locales locales-all
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8

RUN R -e 'install.packages(c(\
              "shiny", \
              "tidyr", \
              "ggplot2"\
            ))'
            
# copy all files into a directory called app
COPY . /app

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 4848)"]
```

The page appears fine locally:
[image: How the page appears when run locally, shapes show up correctly]

But the shapes do not show up correctly if I run the docker container, or if I deploy the [same app to shinyapps.io](https://dkori.shinyapps.io/unicode_fail_example/).

[image: How the shape appears when run on shinyapps.io, or in a docker image]

Session info when run locally:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 21

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.5 tidyr_1.2.1   shiny_1.7.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8       bslib_0.4.0      compiler_4.1.2   pillar_1.8.1     later_1.3.0      jquerylib_0.1.4 
 [7] icons_0.2.0      tools_4.1.2      digest_0.6.30    gtable_0.3.0     tibble_3.1.8     jsonlite_1.8.3  
[13] memoise_2.0.1    lifecycle_1.0.3  pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.6      DBI_1.1.2        cli_3.4.1       
[19] rstudioapi_0.14  xfun_0.34        fastmap_1.1.0    withr_2.5.0      stringr_1.4.1    dplyr_1.0.10    
[25] knitr_1.40       generics_0.1.3   sass_0.4.2       vctrs_0.5.0      rappdirs_0.3.3   grid_4.1.2      
[31] tidyselect_1.2.0 glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.3      purrr_0.3.5      magrittr_2.0.3  
[37] scales_1.1.1     promises_1.2.0.1 htmltools_0.5.3  ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-2
[43] mime_0.12        xtable_1.8-4     httpuv_1.6.6     utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.8    munsell_0.5.0   
[49] cachem_1.0.6
```

Session info from docker container:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.4.0 tidyr_1.2.1   shiny_1.7.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       pillar_1.8.1     compiler_4.2.2   later_1.3.0     
 [5] tools_4.2.2      digest_0.6.30    lifecycle_1.0.3  tibble_3.1.8    
 [9] gtable_0.3.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.6      cli_3.4.1       
[13] DBI_1.1.3        fastmap_1.1.0    withr_2.5.0      dplyr_1.0.10    
[17] generics_0.1.3   vctrs_0.5.0      grid_4.2.2       tidyselect_1.2.0
[21] glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.3      purrr_0.3.5     
[25] magrittr_2.0.3   scales_1.2.1     promises_1.2.0.1 ellipsis_0.3.2  
[29] htmltools_0.5.3  assertthat_0.2.1 mime_0.12        xtable_1.8-4    
[33] colorspace_2.0-3 httpuv_1.6.6     utf8_1.2.2       munsell_0.5.0
```

Edit: based on @SamR's comment, I updated my dockerfile to match the package versions in my local session exactly, and I'm still getting the same error. Updated dockerfile:

```
# get shiny server and R from the rocker project
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.1.2
# system libraries
# Try to only install system libraries you actually need
# Package Manager is a good resource to help discover system deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y locales locales-all
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8

RUN R -e 'install.packages(c(\
"https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_3.3.5.tar.gz",\
"https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyr_1.2.1.tar.gz",\
"https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/shiny/shiny_1.7.3.tar.gz"),\
          repos=NULL,type="source")'
# copy all files into a directory called app
COPY . /app

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 4849)"]
```

@JosefZ mentioned this is a font issue, so I tried manually specifying several different fonts instead, they all still run fine on my local machine and do not run in the container.

Example with font specified in geom_text:

```
    df%>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y),label="\U0001F37C",size=20,
                family = "Lucida Sans Unicode")
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to why it's not working - hopefully someone will know. But as you're creating a docker container, why not use the version of R and the relevant packages where the code works as intended?

Comment: It's a **font** issue…

Comment: @SamR, I'm not that experienced with docker but I edited my post to add an example dockerfile where I manually specify R and package versions to match my local environment. Still having the same issue. 

 @JosefZ, edited my post to add an example using `geom_text` instead of `geom_shape` using the `family` argument to specify the font. It still displays correctly when run on local but doesn't display correctly running on docker, so I'm not sure where else I could/should change the font

Comment: Curious. I don't know why it isn't working. Are you sure `"Lucida Sans Unicode"` is installed? If not `ggplot2` will still display the plot. Running interactively you'll get a warning `In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :  font family not found`. This could get lost in Shiny (you don't see it with `ggsave()`). If you specify a garbage font name do you still get an error? If not try installing the font a different way, e.g. in R with the `extrafont` package.